# How to have limited ZMQ (ZeroMQ - PyZMQ) queue buffer size in python?

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm using `pyzmq` library with **pub/sub** pattern. I have **some fast ZMQ publishers** using `.connect()` method and **a slower ZMQ subscriber** using `.bind()` method.
Then after a few minutes, my subscriber receives the old data published from the publisher — due to ZMQ buffer.

---

## My Question:

Is there any approach to manage **ZMQ queue buffer size?** (set a limited buffer)

[**NOTE**]:

- I don't want to use ZMQ PUSH/PULL.
- I've read this post, but this approach clear buffer only: [clear ZMQ buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619490/how-do-i-clear-the-buffer-upon-start-exit-in-zmq-socket-to-prevent-server-from)
- I also tried with `high watermark` options, but it didn't work:

> ```
> socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVHWM, 10)  # not working
> socket.setsockopt(zmq.SNDHWM, 10)  # not working
> ```

---

**Publisher:**

```
import zmq
import time

port = "5556"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SNDHWM, 10)  # not working

while True:
    data = time.time()
    print("%d" % data)
    socket.send("%d" % data)
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Subscriber:**

```
import zmq
import time

port = "5556"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVHWM, 10)  # not working

while 1:
    time.sleep(2)  # A speed reducer like.
    data = socket.recv()
    print(data)
```

The queue size is still more than 10 despite these options (via configured `send/receive high watermark`).

Comment: Welcome @BenyaminJafari. Could you kindly **expand** a bit your **target definition**, Sir? What are the **{ PASS | FAIL }-criteria** for auditing any approach if the set goal was indeed achieved or not - i.e. for " ***an approach to manage ZMQ queue buffer size*** "? Best using a mandatory-part only, formulated as a MUST_HAVE:-feature list ( with NICE_TO_HAVE:(s) if indeed some such desire dictates some voluntary add-ons ), **that's fair, isn't it?**

Answer (score 7):

I found an approach to get the **last message only** in `ZMQ` subscriber using `CONFLATE` option.

Note that you should set the `CONFLATE` option before you connect:

```
import zmq
import time

port = "5556"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
socket.setsockopt(zmq.CONFLATE, 1)  # last msg only.
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)  # must be placed after above options.

while 1:
    time.sleep(2)  # Dummy delay
    data = socket.recv()
    print(data)
```

In other words, it removes any buffered queue on the subscriber side.

---

[**NOTE**]:

In addition, by using `zmq.SNDBUF` and `zmq.RCVBUF` options we can set a limit on ZMQ buffer size. ([More information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53360536/3702377))

---

Comment: You say "you should set the CONFLATE option **after** you connect", but in your code snippet you set the CONFLATE option **before** connect. I think the code is correct, and the sentence should say **before**.

Comment: keep in mind this unfortunately doesn't work with multipart messages.

Answer (score 0):

To set the queue/buffer size you need to set the high water marks via the socket options

```
setsockopt(zmq.SNDHWM, 10)
setsockopt(zmq.RCVHWM, 10)
```

Comment: I try it before, but not it working, I will updating my question with result of this options.

Comment: Try setting the RCVHWM to 1

Comment: No change happened really.

Comment: You might also need to set the underlying TCP buffer sizes, its hard to eradicate the buffer completely.   You could try the experiment using inproc protocol with two threads instead of TCP as you will have more control over the buffering

Comment: And on the send side you could set conflate if you really only care about the current/latest message

Comment: Check the c++ doc but I think the python will be ZMQ.CONFLATE